# Repeat multiple gridviews?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I want to repeat multiple gridviews.

---

Problem : I have One list of customer on page and if user selects any customer I have to show the 2 grids below each other for that subject consisting different data. Now for each customer I have to show the Details Grid and immediate below that grid have to show Summary Grid. That is working fine But now one new requirement is that, If customer is not selected then I have to show the Details and Summary grid of all customer repeating one after another. 
I have managed show up the data using grids and item template as required, What I did was

---

```
1) Bind Master grid first and on the RowDataBound event get its customer id for that row 
2) On Row RowCreated check if customer is same for current row and previous row if not insert the new row with gridview 
3) And On PreRender Bind that inserted gridview row with the summary data.
```

It is working correctly.

But, I feel that it is not the right way to do it, Is there any other way to achieve this.
Any help would be great. In case of any confusion feel free to comment. If code required of how I did it then please leave comment. I will post my code here.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you use the [Master-Detail View](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/masterdetail/masterdetail.aspx) of the `ASPxGridView`. It is exactly created for this purpose. You can also add summary and other settings to achieve the view you desire.